# Authentication Error while connecting outlook from R

Tags: r

I m trying to connect to outlook from R
But it returns authentication error:

> Error in response_error_handling(e$message[1]) :
> Login denied: the server returned an authentication error

Please help

```
  library(mRpostman)

  con <- configure_imap(url="imaps://outlook.office365.com/",
                    username="*********@*******.com",
                    password=rstudioapi::askForPassword())
  con$select_folder(name = "Inbox")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to Office 365, the email you see is usually an alias and not your "real" email address. For example, we use Office 365 in my company and my email is `allan@company.com`. However, the real address is `3254339@company.com`, where `3254339` is my ID number in the company.
Please, check with your IT department/sector if this is also your case, and create ​the connection token like this

```
con <- configure_imap(
 ​url = "imaps://outlook.office365.com/",
 ​username = "3254339@company.com",
 ​password = rstudioapi::askForPassword()
)
```